# QTMovie pauses on minimize?

Tags: cocoa, quicktime, qtkit

I'm trying to create a video player that plays in the dock when minimized. I'm grabbing the current frame from the QTMovie and intermittently setting it as the minimized icon, but when the window minimizes, the movie (or associated QTMovieView) pauses. How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick test and for me the movie doesn't pause when the window is minimized. You should set a breakpoint at -[QTMovie stop] and see where it's being called from when minimized.